# Exception handling in ContinueWith called infinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, task, continuations

I'm calling an async method (Specifically: Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.SendAsync()) and want to be able to handle the exceptions within.

One possibility I have come across is:

```
_queueClient.SendAsync(message).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + t.Exception.InnerException.GetType().Name);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

However the ContinueWith seems to get called infinitely:

```
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
......................................
......etc
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Any advice on solving this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that it would be orphaned since the onlyonfaulted part of the continuewith should mean that it only runs if the parent task throws an exception.

Comment: If you're seeing this many times then it means that there's a call to `SendAsync` failing for each one.  It's that simple.

Comment: Who/what calls _queueClient.SendAsync?  Is it in a loop?  Behind another service?  Does it have an automatic retry?  Consider logging something from the message to confirm that it is actually the same message each time.

Comment: We are missing the key piece of code which is the method calling `SendAsync`

Comment: Ok so the send is being called within a TraceListener.
And it would seem that the trace listener is picking up my Debug.WriteLines - hence the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the send within a TraceListener which was then picking up the Debug.WriteLine and causing a loop.

The implication is that a TraceListener listens for traces, but it seems it also listens to Debug messages as well.